# Mailjet API retrieving list of all messages inside a campaign

Tags: mailjet

I am trying to retrieve the list of all emails sended inside an Mailjet campaign.

I found "/messagesentstatistics" with $filters = ["CampaignID" => 39483948, "AllMessages" => true] but i only got one message in return.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong. I find strange too that there is no pagination filters available as a campaign could hold a lot of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the `FromTS` filter set to `0` in addition to the `CampaignID`

From The Mailjet API Reference: http://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/messagesentstatistics/